# why am i getting error on windows form designer?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on legacy code in visual studio 2019 and c# and my projects has reference to Telerik component.

All my user control has designer error. Also when I create new empty user-control, I got designer error

I have this problem in current solution and when I create new fresh solution, everything is OK.

Note that I've checked the designer's code several times.

I searched for the problem on Google and tried the following ways

1. reset the visual studio
2. checking the following option:
   Tools >> Options >> Windows Forms
   Designer >> automatically Populate
   Toolbox

here is call stack for error

> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: error is in the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please take a look at [Windows Forms Designer error page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/design-time-errors-in-the-windows-forms-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

hope it help to solve your problem

And some helpful tips in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101715/winform-designer-error-open-designer)